# Table view cell Accessory type Check mark in custom place

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Here is my code,

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Small" ]) {
    cell.imageView.image=nil;
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    return cell;
}
```

But checkmark is adding to the right corner of the cell
I want to add it to another position inside the cell, place like below,

```
[[chkmrk alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, -4, 100, 50)];
```

Comment: take a look [this](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)

Answer (score 1):

try the following code. Actually the `accessory View` is button in the cell. Make a custom cell and inside that cell position the `AccessoryView` layout in the `CustomCell.m` file in `-layoutSubviews` Method. The code is as following:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UIView * arrowView = nil;
    for (UIView* subview in self.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]])
        {
            arrowView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }
    CGRect arrowViewFrame = arrowView.frame;
    arrowViewFrame = CGRectMake(200, -4, 100, 50);
    arrowView.frame = arrowViewFrame;
}
```

This will help you sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could hack it - but safer is to just add new subview with the desired image.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:yourAccesorView];
```

You can control position of that by setting frame.origin.x, y

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to change position of `accessoryView` of `UITableViewCell`. You need to customize your cell.

Such like add button in `cell.contentView` and put image (check/uncheck image) on Button and manage (check or uncheck) it on its click event by button **tag**.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom buttom to your cell where you want, and add an action too. If you do this you can add the button everywhere you want to be placed in the cell.

```
UIButton* yourCustomAccessoryButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[cell addSubview:yourCustomAccessoryButton];
```